# How to initiate MySQL on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: mysql, configuration, my.cnf, mac-os-x

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/04/13/install-mysql-on-mac-os-x-10-6-and-add-startupitem/) to install MySQL on Mac OS X 10.6.8.  Now I get he following errors:

```
$ mysqladmin version
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
$ ls /tmp/mysql.sock
ls: /tmp/mysql.sock: No such file or directory
```

And

```
$ /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
Stopping MySQL database server
$ /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
Starting MySQL database server
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

And

```
$ mysqladmin ping
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
$ mysqladmin -uroot ping
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
$ mysqladmin -uroot -h127.0.0.1 ping
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61'
$ mysqladmin -uroot -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp ping
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61'
$ ls /usr/local/mysql
mysql/                       mysql-5.0.95-osx10.5-x86_64/ 
$ ls /usr/local/mysql/
COPYING         README          configure       docs/           lib/            mysql-test/     share/          support-files/  
INSTALL-BINARY  bin/            data/           include/        man/            scripts/        sql-bench/      tests/          
$ find /usr/local/mysql/ -name mysql.sock
find: /usr/local/mysql//data: Permission denied
$ sudo find /usr/local/mysql/ -name mysql.sock
Password:
$
```

Also, I can't login MySQL:

```
$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
$ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
$ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

And

```
$ /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop 
Stopping MySQL database server
$ /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start --skip-grant-tables
Starting MySQL database server
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/mysql/data/*.err
Password:
ls: /usr/local/mysql/data/*.err: No such file or directory
```

### Re: @Matt Fenwick

```
$ sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
Stopping MySQL database server
$ sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
Starting MySQL database server
$ sudo mysqld -u root
120327 13:03:48 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'root' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

120327 13:03:48 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Volumes/storage/Data/ is case insensitive
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
$ sudo mysqld -u mysql
120327 13:04:11 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Volumes/storage/Data/ is case insensitive
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
$
```

### `my.cnf` used

```
[mysql]
max_allowed_packet=128M
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
user=mysql
datadir=/Volumes/storage/Data
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
innodb_log_file_size=256M
skip-locking
skip-bdb
delay-key-write=OFF
interactive_timeout=3600
wait_timeout=3600
thread_cache_size=128
table_cache=2048
skip-external-locking
max_connections=800
key_buffer_size=64M
read_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=2M
join_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=2M
bulk_insert_buffer_size=10M
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M
max_connect_errors=5000
max_allowed_packet=128M
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:256M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_open_files=1000
```

Comment: If you followed that guide to the letter, what does `/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM status` return?

Comment: Also, try `mdfind mysql.sock` to locate mysql.sock, as it may be creating it in another directory

Comment: Output for `MySQLCOM stop` and `MySQLCOM start` are pasted in OP.

Comment: Also, `mdfind mysql.sock` revealed nothing relevant, AFAICT.

Comment: Sounds like it's not running. What does `ps auxww | grep -i mysqld | grep -v grep` return ?

Comment: It returned empty.

Comment: Please post your my.cnf in your question

Comment: `my.cnf` posted in OP.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem (although I'm on Mac OS X 10.5.8) with all the same error messages.

It turned out the problem was that when the computer was turned on, MySQL was not started automatically.

I solved it by manually starting MySQL:

```
prompt$ sudo mysqld -u root <secure password goes here!>
```

Note the `sudo`:  MySQL wouldn't let me start up the server without root access to **both** the computer and MySQL itself (not that I'm complaining, but it was just frustrating until I figured that out).  Also note that the program is **mysqld**, not `mysql`.

After running that command, everything works fine for me.

Comment: Your method still doesn't seem to fix the issue. See error message in OP.

Comment: @user6076 what doesn't work?  My error messages are **exactly** the same as yours, until I follow my procedure.  Do you not have either root password?  What is the output from `sudo mysqld -u root`?

Comment: See at the bottom of OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed MySQL server using the disk image (.dmg) file then:

Using the Terminal application (bash):

```
sudo su -
nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe &
exit
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar experience and realized I was forgetting the "sudo" in front of the "/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start" command.  Without sudo, it looks like the command completes, but the server isn't running and processes don't start up.  As soon as I added sudo, everything fired up as expected.